# Filtering json data D3.js

Tags: d3.js

I have a line graph that is populated with data in following format:

```
    [{"id":"3",
    "testSource_id":"2",
    "dateTimeTaken":"2013-01-01  14:05:14",
    "dateTimeReceived":"2013-03-01 14:05:45",
    "reading":"0.90000",
    "testSourceLocationDescription":"Somewhere",       
    "parameter_id":"3",
    "inspectionPoint_id":"2",
    "testSourceLowerLimit":"3.000000000000000",
    "testSourceUpperLimit":"11.000000000000000",
    "testSourceLocationLongtitude":"-8.459472656250000",
    "testSourceLocationLatitude":"54.201010239738880",
    "parameterType":"Flouride",
    "unitMeasurement":"F",
    "client_id":"1"},......................
```

I'm trying to filter this data based on a value being passed from a click event on a map. The value - i - is being passed correctly but for some reason my filter function is not returning all the data it should e.g returning an array with 45 objects when should be returning 100?  Can anyone help?

```
d3.json("Data.php", function(error,data) {  
    var data = data.filter(function(d) { return d.inspectionPoint_id == i; })
    console.log(data)

data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.inspectionPoint_id = +d.inspectionPoint_id;
    d.dateTimeTaken = parseDate(d.dateTimeTaken);
    d.reading = +d.reading;
    d.parameterType = d.parameterType;});
```

Comment: Are you sure the value `i` is being passed correctly? Is it coming from somewhere not show? Because in your code above, the function you're passing into the `filter()` method doesn't define (i.e. "accept") an `i` param.

Comment: I agree with meetamit, do you mean: data.filter(function(d,i) { return +d.inspectionPoint_id == i; })

Comment: i is the map marker value that passed from the click event on the map - e.g for each inspection point a marker[i] is added to the map.  If console.log(i) the correct inspection point value is passed.  If do as you said above - data.filter(function(d,i) { return +d.inspectionPoint_id == i; }) not returning correct value - returns array with one object that doesn't contain correct inspection point id?

Comment: see gist: https://gist.github.com/Majella/202df0a4a5a3ad20fb92

Answer (score 0):

is d3.json compatible with .php files?

https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Requests#convenience-methods